# Run the same iPhone app on 2 devices at once?

Tags: iphone, xcode, bluetooth, ios4, gamekit

I have an iPhone app that uses GameKit in Xcode. I'm having problems getting it to work, so I need to look at the NSLog output on the 2 devices at once. My problem is that when I click build and go, it runs it on the device that was connected most recently, and I would like to run it on the 2 devices at once and be able to look at the console output on both. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only run it on one device using Build-And-Go.  To do what you want, install your app on one device using Build and Go, then install it on the other.  On the first, which is now not running through Xcode, open it and run it, then open the Xcode Organizer (CMD-CTRL-o), find your device on the left bar, and click the Console tab.  You will then see the Console Log for this device in the organizer, and the Console Log for the device running in xcode through the XCode console.